# The longest Substring without Repeating Characters

Tags: java, string, algorithm, hashmap

I'm starting out on *LeetCode*, and am currently working on the problem [*Longest Substring Without Repeating Characters*](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-substring-without-repeating-characters/).

> Given a string `s`, find the length of the longest substring without repeating characters.
>
> *Input:* `s = "abcabcbb"`
>
> *Output:* `3`
>
> *Explanation:* The answer is `"abc"`, with the length of `3`.

I feel like my approach should work, but for some reason it fails certain tests (see below). Could someone help me understand why?

```
public int lengthOfLongestSubstring(String s) {
        int current_max = 0; 
        HashMap<Character, Character> seen_values = new HashMap(s.length()); 
        
        int running_count = 0; 
        
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
            if (seen_values.containsKey(s.charAt(i))){
                running_count = 1; 
                seen_values = new HashMap(s.length());
                seen_values.put(s.charAt(i), s.charAt(i));
            } else {
                running_count++;
                if (running_count > current_max){
                    current_max = running_count; 
                }
                seen_values.put(s.charAt(i), s.charAt(i));
            }
        }
        return current_max;
    }
```

***Failed Test***

*Input:*

```
"abac"
```

The code produces *output* `2`, but expected `3`.

This is the only case that I've been able to create where it fails.
Could anyone explain why does it happen?

Comment: When you encounter repetition and do the counter reset, you need to start counting from the index just after the first appearance of the character. for eg:, when you encounter the second ```a``` you should count from ```b``` onwards and the ```running_count``` would be 2 instead of 1

Comment: Not what you asked, but you seem to be using a `HashMap` where a `HashSet` would be more appropriate.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem – Great point – this line of code `seen_values.put(s.charAt(i), s.charAt(i))` would become `seen_values.put(s.charAt(i))` with a Set, definitely looks like a better fit.

Comment: Alexander's answer address the root issue – the _start_ of a substring is separate from if/when you encounter a duplicate character. You'll need to track the start position, and if a duplicate character is seen, save/record the start position, and the max length. Then shift start by one, and search again. Example: `abcda` should have `abcd` and `bcda`, but looks like your code wouldn't find `bcda`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're considering the case when a repeated character has been encountered as the start of a new substring. That's incorrect.

Let's consider the following example:

```
"abcbdef"
```

The longest substring without repeated characters would be `"cbdef"`.

Iteration progresses from substring `"a"` to `"ab"` and then to `"abc"`. At this moment, we encounter the second character `'b'`. Instead of considering it as a start of a new substring, we have to **move the beginning** of the previous substring past the first occurrence of `'b'`, i.e. substring should start from `'c'` (**not** from the second `'b'`).

To implement this logic, instead of maintaining the counter you need to track the starting index of the current substring (as well as maximum substring length).

And instead of `HashMap` you can use `HashSet` as *@Dawood ibn Kareem* has already pointed out in the comments.

While iterating, you need to offer each character to the set, and if method `add()` returns `false` the logic for moving the starting index of the substring needs to be executed. I.e. you need to move the index in the nested loop past the first occurrence of the current character, and **note** that every character encountered in the nested loop has to be removed from the set (apart from the current character).

This approach could be enhanced.

As *@greybeard* has suggested, we skip the step of removing the characters between the *previous* and *new starting position* by storing the index of each encountered character in the `Map` and checking not only whether the *next character* exists but also if the *value* associated with it is greater or equal to the *current starting index*.

That how it can be implemented:

```
public static int lengthOfLongestSubstring(String str) {
    Map<Character, Integer> charToIndex = new HashMap<>(str.length());
    int maxLength = 0;
    int start = 0;
    
    for (int end = 0; end < str.length(); end++) {
        char next = str.charAt(end);
        if (charToIndex.containsKey(next) && charToIndex.get(next) >= start) {
            start = charToIndex.get(next) + 1;
        }
        charToIndex.put(next, end);
        maxLength = Math.max(maxLength,  end - start + 1);
    }
    return maxLength;
}
```

`main()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(lengthOfLongestSubstring("abcbdef"));
    System.out.println(lengthOfLongestSubstring("abac"));
}
```

*Output:*

```
5   // "cbdef"
3   // "bac"
```

Comment: `you can use HashSet [for contains()]`, then again, you may want to keep the index where the character was seen.

Comment: `Without removing them, you might get an incorrect result` when not checking the index kept is lower than the current start index. Then again, without removal the map may grow to alphabet size.

Comment: @greybeard That's a good point, we can ignore an existing entry if the *value* is less than the current *starting index* of the substring. We can spare some operations depending on the contents of the string. Updated the answer with the implementation of this approach.

Answer (score 0):

```js
/*
    Longest Substring Without Repeating Characters

    Example 1:

    Input: s = "abcabcbb"
    Output: 3
    Explanation: The answer is "abc", with the length of 3.
    Example 2:

    Input: s = "bbbbb"
    Output: 1
    Explanation: The answer is "b", with the length of 1.
    Example 3:

    Input: s = "pwwkew"
    Output: 3
    Explanation: The answer is "wke", with the length of 3.
    */

    let str= "pwwkew";
    let result = [];
    let temp = '';
    for (let s of str) { // Iterating each Character from the String
        if (temp.indexOf(s) >= 0) { // Here I am checking if the same String was part of the string.
            result.push(temp); // If we found that the current character is already present in the **temp** variable then we will Push into an array.
// This is Because we will get the shortest and longest all the combinations data.
            temp = s;
        } else {
            temp+= s; // If the character was not already part of the **temp** then we keep on adding on the variable.
        }
    }
// Lets say we reach the end of the string and we have something left on the variable then we must add the string In the result array
    if (temp !== '') {
        result.push(temp);    
    }


    console.log(result);
    result.sort((a,b) => a.length - b.length); // I sorted it in ascending order then the last element would be the longest String.
    console.log('Final Result ---> ', result[result.length - 1])
```